# What's wrong with this simple test?

Tags: javascript

I'm just using a simple compare function. But the result is not consistent.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("Submit");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Answer";

function CheckNums(num1, num2) {
    if (num1 == num2) {
        return "EQUAL";
    } else if (num1 > num2) {
        return "YES";
    } else if (num2 > num1) {
        return "NOPE";
    }
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var firstNum = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    var secondNum = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
    console.log(firstNum, secondNum);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = CheckNums(firstNum, secondNum);
});
```

10 is greater than 0 or 1, but not greater than 5.

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers.

Comment: the submit button is going to cause it to build send request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **+** to convert string to number like this:

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("Submit");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Answer";

function CheckNums(num1,num2){ 
  if(num1 == num2){
    return "EQUAL";
  }
  else if(num1 > num2){
    return "YES"
  ;
  }  
  else if(num2 > num1){
    return "NOPE";     
}}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var firstNum = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
  var secondNum = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
  console.log(firstNum, secondNum);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = CheckNums(+firstNum, +secondNum);
});
```

Comment: @Oliver—that defines an [*HTML input type*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type), not an [*ECMAScript number type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type). All form controls return strings regardless of their HTML type. :-)